# How to pass traceId when creating new coroutine in sleuth?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, spring-cloud-sleuth

How to correctly pass the traceId when creating a new coroutine context? Currently the traceId and spanId is zero when launching a new coroutine.

```
    suspend fun test(event: TestEvent) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            (if anything logged here, it should have the same trace id)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Here you have some tests showing how we instrument the coroutines https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/3.1.x/spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation/src/test/kotlin/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/kotlin/AsContextElementKtTests.kt

Comment: +MDCContext() did it.

Comment: Can you create an answer or modify the question with how you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing mdccontext helped. Now all the logging has the same traceId as the context. That spawned the coroutine.

```
suspend fun test(event: TestEvent) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO+MDCContext()).launch {
            (if anything logged here, it should have the same trace id)
        }
    }
```